# access to file-output of external program

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to call a program from within Python that creates output and I want to work with this output when the external program has finished. 
The programstring is

"sudo fing -r 1 > fingoutput.txt".

I managed to call the program with

```
from subprocess import call

cmd = ['sudo', 'fing', '-r 1']

call(cmd)
```

but I can't direct it's output to a file.

```
cmd = ['sudo', 'fing', '-r 1 > fingoutput.txt']
```

or

```
cmd = ['sudo', 'fing', '-r 1', '> fingoutput.txt']
```

produce

Error: multiple occurrences

I want to write the output to a file because it might be thousands of lines.

Thank you for your help,

Herbert.

Comment: can you show the full error? and what are u trying to do exactly

Comment: My final goal would be to find out which MAC-address is connected to which Port of my HP switches. I could do this with the HP ProCurve Manager which is no longer supported. Meanwhile I scan my network for IP-addresses and their corresponding MAC-addresses. Fing does this. Now I want to read the Fing-output and create a database with networkinformation. Which IP is online, how often and when at last.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stdout` argument to redirect the output of your command to a file:

```
from subprocess import call

cmd = ['sudo', 'fing', '-r 1']
file_ = open('your_file.txt', 'w')  
call(cmd, stdout=file_)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to file from the shell-script itself you can always go for this

```
cmd = 'sudo fing -r 1 > fingoutput.txt'
call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Or

```
cmd = 'sudo fing -r 1 > fingoutput.txt'
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
```

Keeping shell=True may lead to security issues.